# How to enlarge HTML text while keeping its center anchored at a point?

Tags: html, css

How can I animate text on a webpage and increase its size while keeping the center anchored at a point? This is what I have tried:

http://jsfiddle.net/wnn2v023/1/

but as can be seen, the anchor point is at (0, 0) instead of the text center. I tried playing around with `text-align` but couldn't get desired result.

HTML:

```
<button id="button">
  Begin
</button>
<div id="main">
<div id="div">
  Hello World!
</div>  
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#main
{
  position: relative; 
}

#div
{
  position:absolute;
  font-size:0em; 
}

@-webkit-keyframes my-animation {
  0%   { font-size: 0em; }
  100% { font-size: 5em; }
}

.effect {
  -webkit-animation: my-animation 1s; /* Safari 4+ */  
  animation: my-animation 1s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;  
}
```

JS:

```
var e = document.getElementById("button");
var div = document.getElementById("div");
e.addEventListener("click", function()
                  {  
  div.className = "effect";
});
```

Note that I cannot make any changes to the `main` div. Also I found using the `font-size` to animate does not give a very smooth animation.

Comment: Side question: I need to do this in context of a single page game I am developing in HTML5/JS. are there any popular libraries out there to help with animation effects so prevalent in these games?

Comment: Yes. I had tried the text-align property but the trick seems to be to set the width on the div. If the width is omitted, it doesn't work as seen here http://jsfiddle.net/6hpzktdo/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than animating the `font-size` property, animate [`transform: scale()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform).

Set the desired `font-size` on the text along with `transform: scale(0)` and then animation it to its default scale of `transform: scale(1)`:

```js
document.getElementById('button').addEventListener("click", function() {
  document.querySelector('.text').classList.toggle("effect");
});
```

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
}

.text {
  position: absolute;
  transform: scale(0);
  font-size: 5em;
}


@-webkit-keyframes grow {
  100% { transform: scale(1); }
}

@keyframes grow {
  100% { transform: scale(1); }
}

.effect {
  -webkit-animation: grow 1s forwards;
  animation: grow 1s forwards;
}
```

```html
<button id="button">Begin</button>

<div class="container">
  <span class="text">Hello World!</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to specifiy margin:0 auto, try this:[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6hpzktdo/5/)
changed only the css part,

```
#main {
  position: relative;
}

#div {
  margin:0 auto;;
  text-align: center;
  width:82%;
}

@-webkit-keyframes my-animation {
  0% {
    font-size: 0em;
  }
  100% {
    font-size: 5em;
  }
}

.effect {
  -webkit-animation: my-animation 1s;
  /* Safari 4+ */
  animation: my-animation 1s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
```

`